# Regular expression for "This Specific A" formatting rule

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the regex expression that validates a specific rule, but I'm quite a beginner with regular expressions.

## Rule

- There can be any number of words
- Words are space-separated
- Words only contain letters
- Words start with a capital
- The last word must be a single capitalized character

## Expression

Here is where I am so far: `([A-Z][a-z]+[ ]*)*[A-Z]`

## Examples

### Match

- `Example Name A`
- `A New Example C`

### No match

- `a Test B`
- `Wrong Name`
- `Another_Wrong_Name A`
- `Nop3 A`

Comment: `^([A-Z][a-z]* )*[A-Z]$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewbFLZ/1))?

Comment: Ho, absolutely, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- Your regex matches words with two or more letters only before the final one-letter word. You need to match one or more letter words using `[A-Z][a-z]*`
- You use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `[ ]`, to match a single space, and this is redundant, remove brackets.
- You need to match the *entire* string, with [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), `^` and `$`, or `\A` and `\z`/`\Z` (depending on regex flavor).

You can use

```py
^([A-Z][a-z]* )*[A-Z]$
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )*[A-Z]$
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\h)*[A-Z]$
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[^\S\r\n])*[A-Z]$
```

Note `[^\S\r\n]` and `\h` match horizontal whitespace, not just a regular space.

The [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), `(?:...)`, is used merely for grouping patterns without keeping the text they matched in the dedicated memory slot, which is best practice, especially with [repeated groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewbFLZ/1/).